# grep for * in windows with gnuwin grep

Tags: cmd, grep

I would like to grep for * in a text file (test.txt) like:

```
*text1   
blablabla 
*something_else  
another_words
```

so the result should be:

```
*text1
*something_else
```

I tried with gnuwin grep like this:

```
grep '*' test.txt
```

but without success. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: `grep \* test.txt` is working well from the current Cygwin release.

Comment: @lit unfortunately it is giving an error:
grep: \System Volume Information: Is a directory

Comment: that is the error message that should be in the question. I do not know `gnuwin` or it utilities. `System Volume Information` is a hidden directory in the Windows root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a windows native solution like:

```
findstr /B * Rav4_V2.k > grep_star
```

Answer (score 0):

grep by default accepts **regex**, your `'*'` is not valid regex. If you want to search `*`, you can try:

```
grep '[*]' file
```

or if your grep had `-F` option (literal match), you can add `-F` to your command in above question, it should work.

Comment: unfortunately neither '[*]' nor grep -F '*' is working in my windows cmd

Comment: Or `grep '\*' file`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I installed the cygwin terminal. In this terminal 
grep '\*' file is working fine. Thank you

Comment: @Drago Just be aware that `*` has to be escaped or put into a character class whenever you don't want it to have special meaning. In this case, it works because it's at the beginning of the string, but that's an exception.